# Interpolating values in R (and avoiding negative interpolated values)

Tags: r, interpolation

Is there any interpolation approach implemented in R where you can avoid interpolating missing values with negative value?

Let's take a vector:

```
d <- c(NA, NA, 5000, 17782, NA, NA, 21450, 42320, NA, NA, 52900, 54170, 
60600, 69000, 78000, 87000, 96900, 96900, 122000, 132700, 145000, 
171500, 198900, 213400, 229600, 250200, 272000, 291600, 318000, 
343000, 367000, 419200, 445000, 495000, 540000)

plot(d)
```

Using cubic spline interpolation

```
library(zoo)  # for na.spline
d.interpolation <- na.spline(d)
```

this gives

```
[1] -100174.12  -31198.04    5000.00   17782.00   16961.75   14160.17   21450.00   42320.00   53674.83
[10]   54841.83   52900.00   54170.00   60600.00   69000.00   78000.00   87000.00   96900.00   96900.00
[19]  122000.00  132700.00  145000.00  171500.00  198900.00  213400.00  229600.00  250200.00  272000.00
[28]  291600.00  318000.00  343000.00  367000.00  419200.00  445000.00  495000.00  540000.00
```

However, negative values don't make to much sense in this context.

Obviously, something like

```
d.interpolation <- na.spline(c(0,d))
```

also won't work.

Do you have any solution to this?

Comment: Standard warning applies: what do you expect the actual values should be in the `NA` locations?  If your data are expected to be "smooth," for example, you could replace each `NA`  with `mean(d[j-1],d[j+1])` and then do the fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could interpolate over `log(d)`:

```
library(zoo)
d.interpolation <- exp(na.spline(log(d)))
d.interpolation
#  [1]      1.86    282.86   5000.00  17782.00  22424.08  19122.70  21450.00
#  [8]  42320.00  59826.52  58724.79  52900.00  54170.00  60600.00  69000.00
# [15]  78000.00  87000.00  96900.00  96900.00 122000.00 132700.00 145000.00
# [22] 171500.00 198900.00 213400.00 229600.00 250200.00 272000.00 291600.00
# [29] 318000.00 343000.00 367000.00 419200.00 445000.00 495000.00 540000.00
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this option. However, do you know any possiblity how to ensure constantly increasing values? For example `42320, NA, NA, 52900` was replaced by `42320.00  59826.52  58724.79  52900.00`.

Comment: @majom -- are you sure that isn't just due to the spline parameters (essentially high-frequency cutoff) applied to the data?

Comment: Since your data seems to follow an exponential, you could just do a linear inter/extra-polation (instead of using splines) in the log-space. I've seen plenty of questions around that combo on SO.

Comment: Your right for this particular curve `d.interpolation <- na.approx(c(0,d))` looks best.